# when return value from a method,assign that value to a variable first and return that variable is better than return value directly?

Tags: java

When we return value from a method,assign the return value to a variable is better than return value directly without assign to any variable?in the following examples:

```
public int getCustomerId(){
return CustomerService.getCustomerById();
}
```

and another example:

```
 public int getCustomerId(){
int id = CustomerService.getCustomberById();
return id;
}
```

which one is more better and why?I saw one of my friend's code,he assign value to variable first and then return that variable to his service method.

Comment: In theory, the first version might be _slightly_ more efficient because it does not require defining a temporary variable.  In practice, the Java compiler will most likely optimize the second case so that it becomes the first one.

Comment: Which one is easier for you to understand?  That's the better one.  Note that the answer may not be the same in all cases.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,u mean is that If I use second version,It can be more optimize for java compiler?Why?

Comment: A good compiler would be "smart" enough to realize that the variable `id` is only a temporary holder, and it would inline the return statement to look like the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Both the approach are right, it's all depend how much code we are writing in our functions or how much readable our code is.

If it is ***one-two liner code***, i would go for the ***first approach***.

As simple as this, readability is fine.

```
public int getCustomerId(){
  return CustomerService.getCustomerById();
}
```

This makes code little less readable, because just a service call, i need to go through two steps. Extra debugging.

```
public int getCustomerId(){
  int id = CustomerService.getCustomberById();
  return id;
}
```

If i have some ***complex logic written***, maybe at business layer, *`multiple if-else, try-catch`* etc, then **2nd approach** looks fine.

Just an example, and it makes sense

```
 f(){

    Object obj = null;

    try{
        if(condition){
           obj = // call service1
        }else {
          obj = // call service2
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return obj;
}
```

> I agree using extra variable (though local to function), then
>   assignment, might add little overhead to JVM, but code readability
>   should also be considered while coding. JVM is again smart enough to optimize your code as highlighted above.

Refer these [links](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/01/multiple-return-statements.html) for something [more](https://plumbr.eu/blog/performance-blog/how-expensive-is-a-method-call-in-java). Not exactly related but can help.